# music playlists disappear

Tags: iphone, itunes, music.app, car-integration

anyone know a fix to stop this from happening?  Apple says known issue......  1st pic shows settings in Music and phone in iPhone Finder.  I sync all playlists to Phone.  The next 2 pics show what they should be and when they disappear after a few days - not sure what triggers the disappearing.  iOS 14.0.1, Catalina 10.15.7, sync via cable from finder.

Update - so I called Apple again you try for a remedy. Now I’m told that to stop my imported playlist from disappearing I need to be signed in to Music Home Sharing and have an Apple Music account while syncing so that my iPhone will recognize that it’s actually my music and my playlists that I’m syncing over from my computer. Humm - always worked previously w/o all that mumbo jumbo.
2nd UPDATE - 11/13/20 - yesterday when i had the music app up on the phone and got in the car, the phone connected too bluetooth as usual.  I happened to glance down while i opened the music app and right then i saw the music playlists disappear while the phone was connecting to bluetooth.  So now - is it an apple issue or the Toyota Landcruiser???

[image: settings]

[image: should be]

[image: blank]

Comment: If Apple says it's a known issue, then it's an Apple issue.  Your car isn't going to delete playlists because it (usually) doesn't have the ability to create them in the first place. Can you create/edit/delete playlists from your car stereo?

Comment: Hey Allen - well they didint say it was a know issue until the fixes failed and i had called back a 3rd time - seemed like a way to get me off the phone if you know what i mean.  After i bluetooth i see my playlists on the car(if they havent disappeared from the phone) in a list on the stereo then some blank spaces then a few of the playlist names duplictated.  I am unable to create/edit/delete from the car stereo

Comment: Your first sentence, before any of your "updates," said it's a known issue.   That said, issues like this happen all the time after updates - something that works perfectly well is suddenly broken. It's Apple SOP.  And again...your car isn't going to delete playlists because it never (and won't ever) have the ability to do so.

Comment: "Hey Allen - "seemed like a way to get me off the phone if you know what i mean. " I never said the car was deleting them - I said they disappeared while connecting.  As to what caused that, apple or Toyota, i dont know.